# How to change the character composing the Emacs vertical border?

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I am using Emacs 24, console. I am looking for a way to replace the character of the vertical border with another, `\u2502`. Since I didn't find much, I believe it is hardcoded in the source.

Is there any better way to do this, other than recompiling Emacs ? I use many different machines, and thus having this customization inside my `./emacs.d/` would be quite awesome as  a matter of fact ;].

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can change the color of that border, but I don't think you can change it to arbitrary characters (i.e. it had to be an empty block). Is that enough?

Comment: @BruceConnor, It is actually a pipe in console mode, on which you can apply a different background and/or foreground color.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I use this

```
;; Reverse colors for the border to have nicer line  
(set-face-inverse-video-p 'vertical-border nil)
(set-face-background 'vertical-border (face-background 'default))

;; Set symbol for the border
(set-display-table-slot standard-display-table
                        'vertical-border 
                        (make-glyph-code ?┃))
```

Comment: This uses the thicker version. For the thinner version, use `│`.